# Thanks for submitting message not show in Magento contact form

Tags: magento-2.1

I have included contact us form in cms block using below code

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

After submit contact form after thanks message not displayed.

Comment: where you called above static block ?

Comment: I call static block in footer section